# Why does uname return different current hardware platform in different terminals?

Tags: visual-studio-code, uname

I'm on an M2 Macbook Air, running Apple's ARM-based silicon. I want CLI commands related to building my app for different platforms to work correctly and predictably, whether I run those commands from a standalone terminal like iTerm, or the integrated terminal in my IDE.

Strangely, `uname` reports different CPU architecture depending on where I invoke it.

Using iTerm2:

```
$ uname -m
arm64
```

Using the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code:

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

It seems like iTerm gets it right, while VSC gets it wrong.

Both terminals are using the same `uname` program:

```
$ which uname
/usr/bin/uname
```

Both are running the same shell:

```
$ ps -p $$

# iTerm
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
73664 ttys001    0:00.05 /bin/bash -il

# VSC
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
73775 ttys002    0:00.14 /bin/bash --init-file /Users/Tom/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/media/shellIntegration-bash.sh
```

Both list `/bin/bash`. Yes, the VSC one runs that `shellIntegration-bash.sh` script, but I dug through it and didn't see anything that seemed like it would change how `uname` reports the CPU architecture.

Both are loading my bash profile, as evidenced by my custom `PS1` being the same in both places, and I don't have other TTY config in any other files.

I later checked, and VS Code is using Rosetta, while iTerm is not.

What is going on? How can I get `uname -m` to tell the truth in VS Code?

Comment: You might be able to tell if you are running the same uname binaries by hashing them. You could be in an x86 sysroot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Running uname -m Gives x86_64 On M1 Mac Mini](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/420452/479746) on apple.stackexchange.com, when running `uname -m` from a process that is running using [Rosetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)), you get "x86_64". As you later confirmed, your VS Code is running using Rosetta, and your iTerm2 is not. Try [downloading](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) the ARM (Apple Silicon) build of VS Code.

For your reference / learning purposes, that Ask Different Q&A was the first search result for me when I googled "`apple silicon "uname -m"`".